# Matplotlib datetime on the x axis

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

If you have datetime objects on your x-axis how can you get which one was clicked on the click event handler for matplotlib?

I.e when you do this:

```
def onclick2(event):
    print event.x

onClickId = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', OnClick2)
```

I've tried event.x, event.xdata and event._x and they all return ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar problem when trying to return timestamp x axis data from a pandas time-indexed data frame plotted using matplotlib. Attempting Ajean's num2date suggestion on event.xdata returns a float value that is far too large to be a date number (e.g. 23286385.16 for 2014-4-14 2:25).

To expand upon Ajean's suggestion, it is best to first convert the datetime object to a numpy.float64 using the `matplotlib.dates.date2num` function. Then you may use the numpy.float64 array this created as the x-axis with the matplotlib event handler. Returned event.xdata from the event handler may then be converted back to a datetime using `matplotlib.dates.num2date` function.

Answer (score 2):

They probably really are ints ... I believe that matplotlib plots dates by converting them to ints or floats first. Try the `num2date` function in the matplotlib [dates](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) module with your event data, that may yield what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`num2date(…)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date) to get the date back. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726450/232794) for an example of how to use it.