# How to get data in DateTime format from plot with Events in python?

Tags: python, events, pandas, matplotlib

I have data in iPython `DataFrame` like this

```
    Date                        X           Y           Z
0   2015-11-30 20:23:05.556     281.764900  -43.895060  8.714666
1   2015-11-30 20:23:05.757     192.519990  -44.636436  1.720552
2   2015-11-30 20:23:05.958     149.030600  -45.098050  1.958352
3   2015-11-30 20:23:06.171     140.707600  -44.622448  1.510729
4   2015-11-30 20:23:06.366     139.154890  -45.154003  4.783974
5   2015-11-30 20:23:06.564     138.875140  -44.790306  2.266093
```

The `dtypes` of the columns are these:

```
Date    datetime64[ns]
X              float64
Y              float64
Z              float64
dtype: object
```

I set the `button_press_event` to my `fig` like this

```
def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%s, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

and I want to get data from x axes in `Date` format or `String` format, but after click in graph I have just this

```
button=1, x=152, y=339, xdata=735932.856811, ydata=8.518828
```

How to set output from xdata in `String`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib's date support pre-dates numpy's datetime support (and predates `pandas` entirely).  Therefore, it uses its [own internal date convention](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html).

To convert the "raw" number you're getting back to a datetime, use [`matplotlib.dates.num2date`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date).

As an example similar to what you're doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def on_click(event):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        print mdates.num2date(event.xdata)

t = pd.date_range('2015-11-01', '2016-01-06', freq='H')
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, t.size).cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':y}, index=t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
plt.show()
```

Comment: So actually the solution was just put `mdates.num2date(event.xdata)` instead of `event.xdata`. Thank you very much!

Comment: 45 min of search internet to find this answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Joe Kington is not ideal for this situation. This answer is a working solution to this problem (returned a very large number in event.xdata in matplotlib click event when plotting with pandas.plot):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54036315/8564548
Pandas themself solve the solution with [this link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6249355b853878ff06ad8d2affe00d3b629a36ea/pandas/plotting/_timeseries.py#L305)

```
pd.Period(ordinal=int(event.xdata), freq=freq)
```

where freq is the freq of your plot, could be something like '1s', '1min', '1H'... etc